# A class of independence systems given by a probability measure

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $\Omega$ be a finite set and $P$ a probability measure on $\Omega$. Let $ 0\leq\mu\leq1$. The set of subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ such that $P(A)<\mu$ form an [independence system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_system).

Is anything known about such independence systems? I know that in matroid theory a common research theme is to try and characterize certain classes of matroids, is there any simple list of axioms that characterizes my particular class of independence systems? If not, could someone who knows the state of research on matroids take an educated guess at how difficult it might be to obtain such a characterization?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "anything that is known". One obvious property is that any set that admits a weighted cover of total weight $1$ by the sets in your system is also in your system. You can upgrade this observation a little bit but essentially you'll end up just with the dual reformulation on this way (two certain convex hulls are disjoint), which is hardly exciting.

Comment: @fedja It's easy enough to come up with simple necessary conditions - another one is that (for $\mu > \frac 1 2$) the complement of an independent set is independent. I'd like an actual characterization, if possible. I'm mainly asking if this is a type of object that happens to have been defined in the literature before.